# Highlight the tabbaritem with image

Tags: iphone

I have three TabBarItem in a TabBar . And each tabbar item has normal image. I want to highlight the TabBarItem image instead of the normal image.

Can i achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found an answer to your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766144/customize-highlight-image-on-tabbar