# Customize Highlight Image on TabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to replace the normal highlight with an image on tabbar.

What is the simplest way to do this on iOS4 and iOS5??

[image: highlight]

[image: tab bar]

Answer (score 1):

This is super easy in iOS 5 (see the ["Customizing Appearance" section of Apple's UITabBar documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW4)).

If your client is insisting on iOS 4, you'll have to be a bit more creative. Consider subclassing `UITabBar` or `UITabBarController` and doing some drawing of your own.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909379/setting-a-background-image-for-a-tabbar/9021698#9021698) ([and another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640588/really-cool-way-to-create-custom-uitabbar-for-iphone-app) and [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640588/really-cool-way-to-create-custom-uitabbar-for-iphone-app) which has an answer which points to something called [**BCTabBarController**](http://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController)) you can look at.  All great potential solutions for you.

Comment: Subclassing tabbar is allowed on app store?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed on the app store.  As long as you are not using any "private" Apple API's.

Comment: [Private framework API's](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/PrivateFrameworks) are (generally) API's that Apple uses within their own applications to do things, but they're not supported for use by non-Apple apps and Apple therefore rejects apps that attempt to make use of them. If you don't know how to use them, don't worry, you should be safe.